# Python import custom issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm new to python. I have a problem with importing from different relatively folders. PyCharm suggested that I use `python.foldername` and it uses python as root package which is positioned in my root folder of project. It worked when I ran my `main.py` from pycharm
But when I use terminal to run the same file, it broke and it can't work out python.foldername. And I can't import from parent directories

My question is how do I make my root folder as a package like pycharm did

Comment: Pycharm creates a path variable for each project but it not changes the system path, its just like a temporal change. I think it may be the problem here

Comment: I want to know how can I do that. I need to import from parent directories but I can't

Comment: add it to your python path in the environement

Comment: @maazza I saw that solution, but it doesn't sound right to add every project I build to the python path. Is there any way else?

Comment: @maazza have the point

Comment: not every project, just the projects folder (where all projects must be), you can do it in python in fact.

Comment: @KhaledK.Badr use virtualenv :D

Comment: @maazza Thanks it worked. But I want to ask does that work on Heruko as well?. Cause I need to deploy it

Comment: they support virtual envs see  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction

Comment: @maazza Thanks man, I appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is to add it to your python path in your environment/virtualenv.

For heroku see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction